# Command Batch Script In Context Menu not working

Tags: batch-file, command, windows-xp, contextmenu

I have a old batch script from nt/xp that runs from Context Menu. What it does is when I select a folder and run cmd it will create a temp folder in the active folder i right clicked in. Then will run a program to convert all the tiff's in the original folder and output the new images in the temp folder.  New that I using windows 7, I'm having problems getting the CMD.exe to open in the working folder. when I use the script and right click it goes to `/windows/system32` and not the folder I click on.

here are the reg file and batch to show what I want to do:

REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\BW Comp/OV]
@="B&W Compress/OV"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\BW Comp/OV\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\ISRU\\bin\\bwcov.cmd"
```

BATCH file:

```
mkdir temp

FOR %%j in (*.tif) do mr_file -T -S 128 -C j -Q 3 -K g %%~nj.tif temp\%%~nj.tif
```

This was a very simple setup but now with window 7 I can't get it to use the working folder in the batch when making DIR or processing images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
mkdir temp
FOR %%j in (*.tif) do mr_file -T -S 128 -C j -Q 3 -K g "%%~nj.tif" "temp\%%~nj.tif"
popd
```

if `mr_file` is a batch file also then it will need `call` before the name.

This batch file should work in the `SENDTO` menu also

but the registry file looks odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

Foxidrive, I tried your suggestion and that work creating temp folder using folder I right clicked on.

Here are the new files.

Batch File (I used a new program called make_pry instead of mr_file:

```
@echo on
pushd "%~1"
Title %~f1
mkdir temp
FOR %%j in (*.tif) do make_pyr %%~nj.tif -TIFF -JPEG -QFACTOR 97 -tile 128 -out temp\%%~nj.tif
```

And Reg File (this file was also changed and was the only way I could get it to mkdir command to work in batch. If I remove the %1, /a or /c it will not work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\BWCOV]
@="BW Compress OV"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\BWCOV\command]
@="cmd.exe /a /c Inpho_bwcov.cmd %1"
```